# Angular 6's ng serve cannot find @angular/router.ngfactory without re-running ng serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

When I modify anything in my app, up until recently the `ng serve` auto-refreshing of the code to the browser was working (for the most part) perfectly. Now, however, it is not working at all, with **any** change triggering a re-compile, which always outputs the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/msys-modules/main/msys-submodules/manage-views/manage-views.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/router.ngfactory'
```

However, if I Control-C out of `ng serve` and re-run it, it runs perfectly well and ends with `Compiled succesfully`.

I've tried to run `npm install` again, delete the `node_modules` folder and then run `npm install` again, but the problem remains. I'm a bit lost as to where else I can search for the failing module; and why does it work fine if I just recompile it "from scratch"? It's much more time-consuming to have to re-run `ng serve` every time.

The Angular version info is:

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.5
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.4
```

Comment: What version of the CLI are you working with right now?

Comment: @R.Richards added the Angular version info to the question.

Comment: it's a bug from Angular 6.1.2 to Angular 6.1.4 when you compile with -aot, just corrected in Angular 6.1.5. You can update to the lastest angular-cli

Comment: Yes! Updating the core Angular package to the latest version fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Angular core to the latest version:

```
ng update @angular/core
```